# Silencing ringing with volume buttons in iOS 8.1

Tags: iphone, ios

I used to be able to silence the ringtone while my phone was ringing by hitting a volume button.  It appears that this is broken after updating to iOS 8.1.  Does anyone know if this is deliberate, or if it can be reenabled with a setting? Or is this just something that's messed up on my phone?

I couldn't find much in the Apple docs indicating that this was a feature; it's something I discovered myself.  I found some other people who mention this feature as well

- http://support.apple.com/kb/TA38605?viewlocale=en_US (says that it is "archived and no longer updated")
- http://osxdaily.com/2011/02/06/silence-iphone/
- http://teachmeios.com/silence-an-incoming-call-on-the-iphone-in-ios-6/

UPDATE: I have generally found that restarting the phone fixes this for a time, some time after which it will start doing this again.  I really have no ideas here; it's very frustrating.  I can see from the number of views that this question gets that this is a not uncommon problem; if you're lurking, please consider commenting; any new information here might be helpful to future people who experience the problem.

UPDATE(4/1/15): This is driving me crazy -- it works after a restart, but after some amount of time, it stops working again.  An upgrade to iOS 8.2 has failed to fix it as well.  Restarting the phone always fixes it.  Also, when the phone gets in this state, the top button also does not silence the ringer.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean when you say you "couldn't find much in the Apple docs indicating that this was a feature", but then immediately link to an Apple support article detailing the feature.

Comment: Also I just tested this with my iPhone 6 on iOS 8.1, and pressing the volume down button caused the ringtone to silence on an incoming call.

Comment: @tubedogg: the link to Apple is to a page that appears to be deprecated; last updated in 2012 and claiming that it won't be updated any more.  I couldn't find a new, non-deprecated reference.  Thanks for the data point, though -- it's possible that this is just an intermittent thing that would be solved with rebooting, rather than an actual feature change.

Comment: I've always used the top button for this. Single push silence ring still able to answer til end of ring cycle, and a double pressing bounces the caller to voicemail immediately.

Comment: A phone restart has fixed this.  Not sure how I got into a bad state, I guess I'll never know.  As an etiquette thing here, how do I close this question out?